# Concatenating Future Lists in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am reading from 3 separate .json files via futures and want to concatenate them into one list. However, I dont't know how to, since `.add` and `+` seem to not be defined for future Lists. I also struggle to use `then` for further concatenation.
I want to return a Future with values from all 3 json files.
Code:

```
Future<List<Furniture>> getAllHousewares() {
  if (_allHousewares != null) {
    return _allHousewares;
  }

  _allHousewares = rootBundle.loadString("res/raw/housewares.json").then((json) =>
      (jsonDecode(json) as List).map((houseware) => Furniture.fromJson(houseware)).toList());
  _allWallmounteds = rootBundle.loadString("res/raw/Wall-mounted.json").then((json) =>
      (jsonDecode(json) as List).map((wallmounted) => Furniture.fromJson(wallmounted)).toList());
  _allMiscellaneouss = rootBundle.loadString("res/raw/miscellaneous.json").then((json) =>
      (jsonDecode(json) as List).map((miscellaneous) => Furniture.fromJson(miscellaneous)).toList());

  return _allHousewares;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, the best way to handle it is to use the `wait` static method of the `Future` class. The method:

> Waits for multiple futures to complete and collects their results.

Since all of your loaded JSON strings contain the same datatype, you can handle them all the same way with loops which leads to cleaner code. This code uses `await`, which is just syntactic sugar for `.then`.

After the data for each json is processed, it's concatenated with `expand`, though it could have been easily done with the `+` operator as well.

Example:

```dart
Future<List<Furniture>> getAllHousewares() async {
  if (_allHousewares != null) {
    return _allHousewares;
  }

  Future _allHousewares = rootBundle.loadString("res/raw/housewares.json");
  Future _allWallmounteds = rootBundle.loadString("res/raw/Wall-mounted.json");
  Future _allMiscellaneouss = rootBundle.loadString("res/raw/miscellaneous.json");
  
  List combined = await Future.wait([_allHousewares, _allWallmounteds, _allMiscellaneouss ]);
  
  List<List<Furniture>> tempFurniture= List();
  for(String json in combined) {
    tempFurniture.add((jsonDecode(json) as List).map((thingInList) => Furniture.fromJson(thingInList)).toList());
  }

  List<Furniture> furniture = tempFurniture.expand((item) => item).toList();

  return furniture;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it should be `List<List<Furniture>>` and not `Future<List<Furniture>>`?

Comment: @Salatgurke Yes I am sure about this.

Comment: When trying to use this, I am getting an error: `A value of type 'List<Furniture>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<List<Furniture>>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<List<Furniture>>'.` and it occurs here: https://imgur.com/CiH4Hji

Comment: It seems to work, but what I dont get is why you only need to call `jsonDecode(json) as List).map((houseware) => Furniture.fromJson(houseware)).toList());` and thats it.

Comment: @Salatgurke Could you clarify which part you don't understand? I took that directly from you.

Comment: I don't get why it works to call 1 of the 3 futures. I thought I need to call all of them. But just calling `houseware` seems to do the trick

Comment: @Salatgurke I was just copying the code from you. It could be changed to anything and it would still work. I'll do an edit now and if you test it, it will still work. I changed it to `thingInList`, but it will still work the same.

Comment: @Salatgurke Do you understand now? `houseware` was just a parameter of a callback. As long as it was changed in both places it could be changed to nearly anything.

Comment: confused myself there. Thanks